# Session Variable Not Getting Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, session-variables

I am attempting to store a value in a session variable. The value is of type `double`.  Every time I step through my code, my session variable shows a 0 value even though the line above it assigns a value to the variable.  Stepping through my code, `billableamt` ALWAYS has a value, but `Session["bamt"].ToString()` does not.

```
protected void calculate_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  double p;
  double p1;
  double p2;
  double p3;
  double p4;
  double p5;
  double p6;
  p6 = 14.00;
  p4 = 20.00;
  p1 = 10.00;
  billableamt = p + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6;
  Session["bamt"] = billableamt;
  Session["bamt"].ToString();
}
protected void sendmessage()
{
  Session["bamt"].ToString();
}
```

**EDIT**
I expect my session variable to = 44.00

Comment: Did you try this : Session["bamt"].ToString("0.######"); I am not sure if this is the problem though. Number of # depends upon number of values after decimal

Comment: @Partha - this syntax provides compile error of no overload takes 1 argument

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you expect line `Session["bamt"].ToString()` to produce?

Comment: Are you using ASP .Net webform or MVC? Put the break point on Session_Start & Session_End event

Comment: @Jigneshk - webforms and see my edit.

Comment: Is all this code literally as you have shown, or is some of it one location and some in another?

Comment: I tried this above code and initialized other variables (other than P1, P4, P6) to 0.0 and printed the session variable on a label and it works(printed 44). Also Convert.ToDouble(Session["bamt"]).ToString("0.00") prints 44.00

Comment: Did you put the debug point in Session_Start & Session_End function? You can find this functions in Global.asax.cs file. Restart the "ASP .Net State Service", if its not running start it.

Comment: @Partha - that was a good idea to write to labels.  I tested and confirmed that it writes properly from my calculate() but it is NOT from my sendmessage()

Comment: Where are you calling sendmessage() ?

Comment: @Partha from the same class, just a separate button click event.

Comment: try to add try catch to your code coz it seems that there's an error on `billableamt = p + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6;`

Comment: I tried that too and it works. Are you sure you click calculate before clicking other button ?

Answer (score 0):

["Remember that using uninitialized variables in C# is not allowed."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
see how partha initialized variables in his comment? that's why it worked.